# C# doesn't recognize C++/CLI namespace without .cpp file

Tags: c#, c++-cli, clr

I have a CLR solution with C# project referenced to Managed C++ project. The C# entry point is Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
using ManagedCpp;

class Program
{
    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ManagedClass mc = new ManagedClass();
    }
}
```

ManagedCpp.h

```
#include "NativeClass.h"
namespace ManagedCpp {

public ref class ManagedClass
{
private:
    NativeClass* _ptr = nullptr;

public:
    ManagedClass() { _ptr = new NativeClass(); };
    ~ManagedClass() { if (_ptr) { delete _ptr; _ptr = nullptr; } };

    void ThrowException() {
        try
        {
            _ptr->ThrowException();
        }
        catch (std::exception e)
        {
            throw gcnew System::Exception(gcnew System::String(e.what()));
        }
    }

};
}
```

After compiling the Managed C++ project and run, it gives out this error:

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ManagedCpp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

However, if I move the function bodies from ManagedCpp.h to a ManagedCpp.cpp file. The program run without problem:

New ManagedCpp.h

```
#include "NativeClass.h"
namespace ManagedCpp {


public ref class ManagedClass
{
private:
    NativeClass* _ptr = nullptr;

public:
    ManagedClass();
    ~ManagedClass();

    void ThrowException() {
        try
        {
            _ptr->ThrowException();
        }
        catch (std::exception e)
        {
            throw gcnew System::Exception(gcnew System::String(e.what()));
        }
    }

};
}
```

New ManagedCpp.cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ManagedCpp.h"

ManagedCpp::ManagedClass::ManagedClass() { _ptr = new NativeClass(); }
ManagedCpp::ManagedClass::~ManagedClass() { if (_ptr) { delete _ptr; _ptr = nullptr; } }
```

What's the difference between the two? Why the later case C# can see the namespace but not the first case?

Comment: "_After compiling the Managed C++ project and run, it gives out this error:_" How could you build and run it? The error you get is a compiler error (as indicated by form of the ID `CS****`) Getting a compiler error means the compiler **failed** to build. If the build failed, there is nothing to run (except perhaps by accident running a leftover old/outdated compiled program from a previous build attempt that succeeded)

Comment: Note that a header file as such is not a "stand-alone" compilable unit (usually). It will usually be #included in some .c/.cpp source file, with the .c/.cpp source file being the compilable unit. Now, if you were to have an empty .c/.cpp source file without `#include "ManagedCpp.h"` (or no .c/.cpp file at all) then any code in the header file would simply **not** be compiled...

Comment: Stick with the "new cpp file", it is obviously correct.  Whether the code you didn't post properly #includes the .h file is hard to see.  Probably not because you didn't post it.  Next thing you need to do is wonder whether there is any point in putting that class in a .h file.  If you do it right then there isn't, .NET uses assembly metadata and not .h files to expose declarations.  They still got a hard time getting modules formalized in the C++ standard, C++/CLI didn't wait for that.